# POST method is not executing to fill form which saves values to database

Tags: python, html, django, database

I am a newbie to django framework and want to take values and save it to database. for this i used post method but when i check it is executing else part. I went through previous question on it but still found unsatisfying in my case.
Code is as follow:

```
#views.py

from django.shortcuts import render, render_to_response
from django.http import HttpResponse, HttpResponseRedirect
from .models import StudentInfo, History
from django.shortcuts import get_object_or_404, render
from .forms import Info


def index(request):
    return HttpResponse("Hello, world")
def info(request):
    if request.method == "POST":
        the_form=Info(request.POST or None)
        context={
            "form": the_form
        }
        if form.is_valid():
            form.save()
    else:
        return HttpResponse("It sucks")
    return render(request, 'details.html', context)

#models.py

from __future__ import unicode_literals

from django.db import models

 # Create your models here.
class StudentInfo(models.Model):
        name=models.CharField(max_length=40, help_text="Enter Name")
        reg_no=models.IntegerField(help_text='Enter your reg_no',  primary_key=True)
    email=models.EmailField(help_text='Enter email')
        def __str__(self):
           return self.name

class History(models.Model):
    Reg_no=models.ForeignKey('StudentInfo', on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    date=models.DateTimeField(auto_now=True)
    def was_published_recently(self):
       return self.date >= timezone.now() - datetime.timedelta(days=1)

#forms.py


from django import forms
from .models import StudentInfo, History
class Info(forms.ModelForm):
    name= forms.CharField(label= 'Enter name')
    reg_no= forms.CharField(label= 'Enter registration no.')
    email= forms.EmailField(label= 'Enter email')
   class Meta:
        model= StudentInfo
        fields= ['name', 'reg_no', 'email',]

#details.html
<h1>Enter the details</h1>
<form action="{% url 'auto:info'  %}" method="post">
{% csrf_token %}
{{ form.as_p }}
<input type="submit" value="Go" />
</form>
```

Comment: At the moment your view `info` clashes with your model form `info`. You should use `lowercase_with_underscores` e.g. `index`, `info` for function based views, and `CamelCase` e.g. `StudentInfo`, `Info` for your model/form classes. You are using the obsolete `render_to_response` incorrectly, you should use `render(request, template_name, context)` instead.

Comment: I changed model names (ie.' StudentInfo, History'), form(Info), view (info function) remain same except i used render instead of render_to_response still not working. Still it is executing else part ie it sucks.

Comment: If you have changed the code, please [edit] your question.

Comment: Done sir please have a look @Alasdair

Comment: If you are submitting the form from the `details.html` template above and it uses the `info` view, then it should work, because you have `method="post"` in the form. Double check the indentation in your view, and make sure you don't have any tabs. Apart from that, I'm afraid I don't have any other suggestions. Hope you figure out the problem.

Answer (score 0):

```
if form.is_valid():
    form.save()
```

You should use `the_form` instead of `form` since that's what you called the output of `info(...)`

Comment: i tried it's not working. It is not entering the if part as again it is executing else part